# Laravel delete() static call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got this error:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::delete() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Here is the code in my controller:

```
$file_db = new File();
$file_db = $file_db->where('id',$id)->find($id);
$file_db = $file_db->delete();
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to call it correctly?

Comment: can you provide more code? this seems fine to me

Comment: file is a model right?

Comment: Code from model //$record = self::where('id',$id)->first();  $record->delete();

Comment: yes file is a model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this:

```
$file_db = $file_db->where('id',$id)->find($id);
```

But you should be doing this:

```
$file = File::where('id', $id)->first(); // File::find($id)

if($file) {

    return $file->delete();
}
```

Comment: it throws out error "
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::delete() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context" but the kicker is it deletes the row from database

Comment: In this example, I didn't call delete method statically so check other places.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete model with specific `id`, use the `destroy()` method.

```
File::destroy($id)
```

Answer (score 1):

may be
 `File::find($id)->delete();`

Comment: The accepted answer contains this solution.